# Запятая перед союзом "и" в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "и". Можно ли считать "у бабушки" общим второстепенным членом: У бабушки трое внуков и уже даже есть маленький правнук.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы: в вашем предложении "у бабушки" - это общий второстепенный член.К нему  от обоих сказуемых можно задать один и тот же вопрос. Запятая не нужна.